# Why did Poké Balls not work in the seventh movie?

Tags: technology, pokemon

In the seventh *Pokémon* movie, *[Pokémon: Destiny Deoxys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon:_Destiny_Deoxys)* (2004), Poké Balls stop working after Deoxys fully awakens and his presence starts interfering with electronics.

I remember that there is a scene where a character says something like...

> Even the XXX system isn't working

... followed by several minor characters pressing the buttons on their Poké Balls with no response.

What is the name of the system the Poké Balls needed to work? I don't have a copy of the the movie anymore, or I would look it up myself.

Comment: I think it's a shame they didn't just call it _Pokemon: The Seventh Movie_, as a callback to the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/M07

> Rebecca is glad to learn that the backup generators have kept the lights on, but remarks that even the Poké Ball Management System isn't working.

With the precise line [likely](https://subslikescript.com/movie/Pokmon_the_Movie_Destiny_Deoxys-435286#:%7E:text=Even%20the%20Pok%C3%A9ball%20management%0Asystem%20isn%27t%20functioning) being:

> "Even the Pokéball Management System isn't functioning."

With some amount of choice on whether to put a space in "Pokéball".

Comment: So let me get this straight: You can make a Pokéball out of apricorns and other random crap you picked up off the ground (see *Pokémon Legends: Arceus*), but it requires a computer system in order to actually work? Did the Galaxy Team have an underground data center or something that we never get to see?

Comment: @Kevin - Well, modern Poke Balls might work differently than ones made hundreds of years in the past. Transmission of Pokemon via computers is a Bill innovation or something, right?